# FTP server returns 530 (Not logged in) when running from Azure function on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, ftp, azure-functions

I am trying to upload a file to FTP server using azure function. It finds the file on azure file share and tries to upload it, fairly simple.

```
        byte[] fileContents;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await file.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
            fileContents = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"ftp://{ftpAddress}/{fileName}");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        }

        using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            log.LogInformation("HTTP triggered function executed successfully");
            return new OkObjectResult($"File uploaded successfully on the FTP - response from the server: {response.StatusCode} - {response.StatusDescription}");
        }
```

It works well when running Azure Function locally, but it does fail when running from Azure.

I've been trying multiple things, with UsePassive etc., but nothing seems to work. I do have however a "@" sign in the password and I am quite sure that I need to escape it, I just don't know how. I'd appreciate any help, thanks.

**@EDIT**
I just checked with a plain text password and it doesn't work either...

**@EDIT2**
I used FluentFTP for the same FTP server and I did get 530 but with the "login incorrect" message. Then I tried with different FTP server

[dlptest](https://dlptest.com/sample-data/)

and both methods worked. Any idea what might be wrong with the login? I has dashes and underscore, so could that be a reason?

**@SOLVED**
I haven't actually changed nothing in the code, just check different FTP server, also with credentials having special characters and it works fine on that. Anyway, thanks for help : )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can see my test file in `C:\home\site\wwwroot\aa.bak`. And use code like you, it works fine.

So I recommand you, try my code, and check the result. If the problem is solved, then it is really great.

If not, I dare to conclude that there is a problem with your file reading. And you need check below code. Or show more details for us.

```
file.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
```

**My Sample Code:**

```
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        //string ftpAddress = "waws-prod-dm1-037.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot/aa.bak";
        string ftpUser = @"jasontest11\$jasontest11";
        string ftpPassword = "BRPF****Yppms";
        byte[] fileContents;
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\home\site\wwwroot\aa.bak"));
        fileContents = memoryStream.ToArray();

        FtpWebRequest request;
        //request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(string.Format(@"ftp://{0}", ftpAddress))) as FtpWebRequest;
        request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create($"ftp://w***37.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot/aa1122.bak");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPassword);
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        try
        {

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            req.CreateResponse(((FtpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription.ToString());
        }
        return req.CreateResponse("Upload Success");
    }
}
```

**My Test Result:**

[image]

Comment: I will give it a try, thanks. I am working on some other FTP server to see if it works there.